# What type of 16x02 LCD display is this?

Tags: character-lcd

A buddy of mine has this defect display. It comes out of a [Lenz LH100](https://www.dccconcepts.com/manual/lenz-owners-manual-lh100-throttle-handset/) handheld throttle. He is looking for a replacement and the company in question is not going to send one. From the looks of it, it seems to be a regular 16x02 display.

[image]

Comment: I changed the link to be to the owner's manual, which clearly shows it is not a 16x2 display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be a 16x2 display.

You are mixing it with LH101 display which seems to have 16x2 dot matrix kind of display and this LH100 model has a simpler 7-segment kind of display.

The 16x2 dot matrix type with e.g. 7x5 characters would require at least 16 common pins and 80 segment pins. And there are only a few pins which indicates a simpler 7-segment type display with custom segments. It's also a bare LCD glass without a driver chip as the driver is on PCB.

Likely a custom display which can't be bought, unless extracted from a broken donor.